# Access different tables in CakePHP

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

I was wondering if there is a way to specify which table(s) you want to update on form submission. For instance,

I am using the Orders model, which uses the CustomerOrder table. I want to have an edit_company action/page that updates the customer table.

Here is a bit of the code:

```
class Order extends AppModel{
public $useTable = 'CustomerOrder';
public $primaryKey = 'OrderID';
public $belongsTo = array(
    "SalesAgent"=>array(
        "className"=>"User",
        "foreignKey"=>"UserID"
    ),
    "CampaignCustomer"=>array(
        "foreignKey"=>"CampaignCustomerID"
    ),
    "ShippingMethod"=>array(
        "foreignKey"=>"ShippingMethodID"
    ),
    "OrderStatus"=>array(
        "foreignKey"=>"OrderStatusID"
    )
);
public $hasMany = array(
    "OrderEntry"=>array(
        "foreignKey"=>"OrderID",
        "finderQuery"=>'SELECT * FROM [OrderEntry] AS [OrderEntry] INNER JOIN [Product] AS [Product] ON [Product].[ProductID] = [OrderEntry].[ProductID] WHERE [OrderEntry].[OrderID] IN ({$__cakeID__$}) AND [OrderEntry].[Quantity] > 0'
    ),
    "Payment"=>array(
        "foreignKey"=>"OrderID"
    ),
    "ShippingLabel"=>array("foreignKey"=>"OrderID"),
    "Note"=>array(
        "foreignKey"=>"OrderID",
        "finderQuery"=>'SELECT * FROM [Note] AS [Note] INNER JOIN [UserAccount] AS [User] ON [User].[UserID] = [Note].[UserID] WHERE [Note].[OrderID] IN ({$__cakeID__$}) ORDER BY [CreatedDate] ASC'
    ),
    'ShippingLabel'=>array(
        "foreignKey"=>"OrderID"
    ),

);
public $order = array(
    "Order.OrderID"=>"desc"
);
public function afterFind($results,$primary=false){
    if($primary && isset($results[0]['CampaignCustomer']) && !empty($results[0]['CampaignCustomer']['CampaignCustomerID'])){
        foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
            $company = $this->CampaignCustomer->Company->find("first",array("conditions"=>array("Company.CustomerID"=>$val['CampaignCustomer']['CustomerID']),"contain"=>array()));
            $campaign = $this->CampaignCustomer->Campaign->find("first",array("conditions"=>array("Campaign.CampaignID"=>$val['CampaignCustomer']['CampaignID']),"contain"=>array()));
            $results[$key]['Company'] = $company['Company'];
            $results[$key]['Campaign'] = $campaign['Campaign'];
            //unset($results[$key]['CampaignCustomer']);
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Could anyone help me with this?
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which controller your form is using when creating it. 
You have an `url` option to set it :

```
echo $this->Form->create($customer, [
    'url' => ['controller' => 'Customer', 'action' => 'edit']
]);
```

Here, your request will be sent to `edit` action in `CustomerController`.
Doc : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#setting-the-controller-action-for-the-form